# Why am I getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'else' in if elseif elseif else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

I have been looking for similar problems but they all seem to have one mistake with ";" but I can't find mine. I have been looking for a while now. Help would be much appreciated.

```
<script>
var Input= prompt();
var Counter = 0;
  
for (Counter<Input;Counter++;)
   {
     if ((Counter%5===0)&&Counter%3===0)
         {console.log('Fizzbuzz'); 
  }
    elseif((Counter%5)===0)  
         {console.log('Buzz'); C
  }
    elseif((Counter%3)===0)
     {console.log('Fizz');    
  }
   
     else {
   console.log(Counter); 
  
  };
     
   };
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have an `elseif` keyword. It's `else`, followed by an `if` statement.

Comment: check here for your answer https://code.sololearn.com/Wa39A86A7a24